# Ruby extract id from a string text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to Ruby and I have a doubt regarding extracting something from a string.

I have a string with the following value.

```
Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking
```

I need to extract the id from this string.

The steps should be something like extract string from the first occurrence of "ID[space]" to the next [space].

Is there a way to do this in Ruby?

Comment: `'Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking'[/ID:\s+(\S+)/, 1]` `=> "101"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way is to use *Regex*

Find the number which comes after "Booking ID: "

```
booking_title = "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking"
bookind_id = booking_title.match(/(?:Booking ID:\s)([\d]+)/)
```

Find the first number in string

```
booking_title = "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking"
bookind_id = booking_title.match(/[\d]+/)
```

Shorter Syntax

```
booking_title = "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking"
bookind_id = booking_title[/[\d]+/]
```

Comment: the second part was what I wanted. It worked! thanks :-)

Comment: That's some awesome syntax. I have updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions:

```
irb
irb(main):001:0> "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking".match /\d+/
=> #<MatchData "101">
irb(main):002:0> "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking".match(/\d+/).to_s
=> "101"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by splits as well, regex depend that the words will be always the same for Booking ID: .... Name:.... and the following as well should work same:

```
text = "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking"
booking_id = text.split(":")[1].split("Name")[0].to_i        # 101
```

OR

```
booking_id = text.split(":")[1].strip.split(" ")[0].to_i
```

You have many ways to do it.

Comment: Easy to understand and build if you are not comfortable to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
booking_title = "Booking ID: 101 Name: Booking"

booking_id = booking_title.scan(/\d/).join('')
```